# Tex: Put two column sentences and one table on one page with SIAM template

Tags: latex, tex

I'm writing a supplementary material for SIAM International Conference on Data Mining (SDM).
I'm using the following SIAM template with two column.
https://www.siam.org/Portals/0/Conferences/Proceedings/soda2e_031819.zip

How can we put small sentences and one column table on one page?
I show the example although it needs two pages with a big space.

```
\documentclass[twoside,leqno,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltexpprt}

\begin{document}
\title{Table test}
\author{Author1}
\date{}
\maketitle
\fancyfoot[R]{\scriptsize{Copyright \textcopyright\ 20XX by SIAM\\
Unauthorized reproduction of this article is prohibited}}

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Test1.}
Table~\ref{tbl:test} is a test table.

\begin{table*}[htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Test table.}
 \label{tbl:test}
 \begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c } \hline
  & t1 & t2 & t3 & t4 \\ \hline
a & b  & c  & d  & e  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF image of the above TEX example]

Comment: You should probably post this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I agree with @absolutelydevastated. However, have you tried to use `\table*[H]` instead of `\table*[htbp]`?